# How to hibernate seamless windows XP mode under windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-virtual-pc, windows-xp-mode

My windows XP mode runs seamlessly under windows 7. i.e., applications are opened on windows 7 desktop, and there is no virtual PC desktop.

I want to hibernate the virtual machine, but there are no controls I can use.
any ideas?

Comment: Hi Andre, welcome to Stack Overflow. You seem to be asking a lot of questions about microsoft virtual PC, which are really more appropriate for a site like SuperUser. This site is for programming questions. If these questions are migrated, don't be alarmed.

Answer (score 0):

When you close the application that runs in XP mode, its virtual machine is hibernated. When you run the app again, the vm wakes up. You don't need to manage that VM yourself.

Comment: I'd like to clarify the question: How to hibernate the machine WITHOUT closing the virtual apps?

Comment: I don't know how, if you even can. If you want that kind of control, just get yourself a regular VPC of XP, and install the apps in that. The whole point of XP mode is that the VM is invisible and people don't think about it. You don't have to use it. I have an XP VPC that I launch when I demo app compat issues - I can sleep/wake/hibernate that machine, regardless of the state of the apps running in it.